# Is it possible to deliver RTSP stream via Kurento. WebRTC to RTSP

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I want to use Kurento as media server which takes WebRTC as an input and provides RTSP stream as url: `rtsp://kurento/streamName`

Is this possible?

I saw https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc/ project which does opposite thing.

My final goal is to deliver a stream to mobile browsers via JSMPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as Kurento team says: ["We can consume it, but not produce it."](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/kurento/cVqvsV2tW5A/dLJF53iRCAAJ)
Now, as a common solution for this, you could stream from Kurento to Wowza media server using an RTP endpoint, and then re-stream RTSP from Wowza. In KMS google group there is a lot of content related to the integration between the two of them.